# IIoT Sound Classification with Little Data

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, overfitting, audio-recognition

**[Problem Statement]** I have been working on a sound a classification problem with less 200 sound files (wav format) with the following imbalanced class distribution:

```
Class1 110
Class2 50
Class3 20
Class4 12
```

Here are Time-Amplitude representation based on `librosa.display.waveplot` for a random sample from each class:
[image]

At present I am either over-fitting or have a low train/test accuracy. I am aware the more training data the better esp. for Class3 and Class4, however, since data labelling for this task is an expensive process, I am exploring ways to avoid that as much as I can, and still obtain a decent model (e.g. a model with about 90% validation accuracy) with data at hand. Sounds are from a machine in a manufacturing line, thus naturally noisy and with varying lengths for each Class.

**[Attempts]** So far I have tried the followings:

- Mel-Spectrogram representation:
  I have converted audio files to log-scale Mel-Spectrogram (basically images as shown below) and performed a multi-class image classification, as well as transfer learning. Also I have used Google AutoML Vision to conduct transfer learning. Whatever I do, I cannot do better than 60-65% accuracy.
  [image]
- Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients (MFCCs):
  I have tried to extract MFCCs features using `librosa` as below:

> ```
> audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file, res_type='kaiser_fast') 
> mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
> mfccsscaled = np.mean(mfccs.T,axis=0)
> ```

and feed extracted features into a Fully Connected NN (FCNN) or CNN. YET I have facing not-easily-solvable over-fitting (things I have looked at: model architecture e.g. very simple to complex, regularization via l1 or l2 regularizers, class weight, feature scaling, batch normalizations, weight initializers, dropout, optimizers, change of loss, learning rate more and more), still I get somewhat like:
[image: Model Optimization Graphs]

Most likely due to this over-fitting, I am facing a known only-one-class prediction (meaning NN mostly predicts one class), and strangely, this class is in fact a minority Class3!

**[Questions]**

- Are there any other methods like Transfer Learning for Images but for Audios?
- How about WaveNet, and directly train on Audio files? I cannot seem to find an official implementation, or at least something reliable. Anyone experienced using WaveNet?
- Any recommendations how to make this model somehow better? I am leaning towards the fact it is within the nature of the audios, that is hard to distinguish, still I don't get it how model can be fooled on the training set up to 100% accuracy then (well accuracy might be a good indicator as well).

I have looked/am still looking into many posts, examples, suggestions to tackle this problem (list is too long, I wouldn't list them here), but rather curious if there are anything that I fundamentally miss here. Maybe simply I gotta stop and collect more data at any costs (although I doubt that would solve the problem completely), what if noise is my enemy!

**[Last but not least, Data Collection]** It may a bit biased towards certain samples/classes. Image below shows a schematic view how it is done at the moment:

[image]

Blue shows a box where certain items (shown in black) are inserted. Microphone that is placed at the top side of the box records each of these black-item placement for inspection. However, it is noted that distance from Microphone varies to the items by 5-10 cm! For example, black items on the left may all belong to Class2, but still produce a slightly different sound wave due to their varying position to the Mic. This may be negligible, but cannot be just yet ruled out!

Comment: Have you tried using an audio embedding model as feature extractor? Like OpenL3 or VGGish?

Comment: When you did the Mel spectrogram model, did you use analysis windows? Typically around 1 second long. And maybe 0.1 hop between windows. Then aggregate the predictions

Comment: What kind of data augmentation have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. No I haven't tried audio embedding, I was looking for a hint that such thing exists. I will look at OpenL3 or VGGish, in fact I was learning about EdgeL3 this morning. I am not sure it is built on top of those you mentioned, but it s audio embedding in a super easy manner. And about Mel., no I have not looked into win. And so far not data augmentations too. Apparently there are many to check out. Do you have any hints for data augmentations or I can easily find by googling...?!

Comment: Using analysis windows, each window shifted less than the (overlapping windows) is a key data augmentation technique. So start with that. The other classics are pitch shift / time-scretch. Some sort of cutout can be useful as well. See SpecAugment for example. Some type of Mixup can also help

Comment: Btw, you should estimate human level performance on the task/data. Sample some examples of each class (say 5), randomize presentation and ask people to put them into the 4 different classes. If the persons are not familiar with the sounds from before, show them 1 example of each class before asking them.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and valuable recommendations. I will give them a try one at a time. I have actually started off with the audio embedding (OpenL3 or EdgeL3), I am facing a technical problem. From embedding out would be 1) varying sizes because audios are having varying length, I am assuming I should be padding, right? 2) But related to that, from embedding I get an array element with a sequence like array([[1.4160953, 1.4692091, ...],
         [1.4372598, 1.4085318, ...]...]), size of each is (x, embedding_size = 512)! How should I with post-process this array for classification?

Comment: If lengths are reasonably similar, just truncate to closet embedding time-frame. Then you can try to classify each embedding time-frame independently and aggregate predictions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862626/keras-how-to-aggregate-over-frame-level-predictions-to-song-level-prediction/55267520#55267520). Alternatively you can aggregate the embeddings along time into one feature vector and classify that. Mean+std for example. Or you can try go concat the embeddings into a time-series and use that as inputs.

Comment: You are being huge help, thanks. Nice weekend!

Comment: You're welcome! We do a lot of this kind of things at $dayjob soundsensing.no